# Is it not possible to generate random numbers directly inside a fillStyle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, random

Maybe I'm not using Math.random() correctly, although I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(Math.floor(Math.random()*256),Math.floor(Math.random()*256),Math.floor(Math.random()*256))";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fillStyle is a string. You need to use string concatenation to do what you want. Like this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+
  Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+
  Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+
  Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+")";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Comment: is there a way to store an rgb value (or rgba or however you do a bw or bwa) as a var?  As in: color myCol = rgb(0,255,96);
Or would I just then store it as a string, like var myCol = "rgb(0,255,96)";

Comment: Nevermind, that question is essentially answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088366/rgb-value-as-variable) (and it seems that the answer is "yes, it's a string")

Comment: From Paul Irish: ctx.fillStyle = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)